# Reverse lights stay on

Tags: electrical, explorer, wiring-diagram, reverse-lights

I have a 1999 Ford Explorer 
my reverse lights stay on with or without the key in the ignition 
Please Help me I don t know what to do
I have had to replace the window  and Lights fuses several times. Keeps blowing/Popping

Comment: The very first thing to do is to take the bulbs out because otherwise they'll flatten your battery.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that there is a connection between a permanent live and the reverse light wire, probably in the boot area.

This is because :
One, reverse lights usually work only with the ignition on and these are on all the time.

Two, if the false connection was prior to the switch and the switch has not failed, then the lights would go out when not in reverse.

Three, you have existing issues with fuses blowing : which leads me to suspect some damage somewhere...

So, this connection / damage has to be found - check all the rear wiring - has it got a tow bar? Has a connection been made, in error, with a live wire? Some people, when fitting tow bar wiring use whatever colours come to hand and the functions don’t match the colours...

Comment: Yes it does appear the reverse light circuit is only hot with key in run position on that model.

Answer (score 1):

You have a defective reverse light switch, which is screwed into the transmission. C172 in the image below.

Fairly easy fix to replace it with a new one. Disconnect harness from switch, unscrew switch from transmission, screw in new switch, reconnect wire harness.

**NOTE**: If this does not fix the issue then it is a wiring problem, the reverse lamp circuit is shorted to a hot at all times wire somewhere in the harness.

[image]

Comment: I would think that something else is wrong as well.  Normally with the engine off the backup lights won't be on. I always part stickshift cars in reverse.  I would think it would be the same with automatics, although you normally can't take the key out of the ignition unless it's in park.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the sensor/switch in your gear-leaver / drive mode selector for reverse is broken.

[This site](https://www.ford-trucks.com/forums/1096352-reverse-lights-not-working.html) suggest you need to replace it and it can be done from below the car. But I´m not to sure about model years so may be implemented a bit different with yours.